# SSRS ReportServer returns 404 but only after Angular site has been loaded

Tags: angular, reporting-services

I am working on a website that is hosted in IIS 8.5.  The website has links to the SSRS ReportViewer.

We have started to rewrite the website using an ASP.NET Core backend and an Angular front end.  We have not started to rewrite the link to the ReportServer, our plan is to have a transition phase where the old and new websites are available together and the functionality will migrate slowly.  We have just recently deployed the new website for the first time and are experiencing a strange issue.

The user logs into the original website.  They click on a link and are sent to view a report using the ReportViewer (this link works).  The user then navigates to the new site in a separate browser tab.  When the user clicks back to the original tab and attempts to click the same report, the link to the ReportViewer is broken and a 404 error is shown.

To be clear, the website has a url like

https://domainname/website

and an example of a report url is

https://domainname/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/customer/args

The angular site is hosted on

https://domainname/angularwebsite

I realise that ReportViewer is no longer hosted in IIS.  It seems that once the Angular site is accessed, it overwrites the ReportViewer site.  Closing the browser tab that is displaying the Angular site does not fix the issue.  However clearing the browser cache and reloading the ReportViewer tab allows the user to view reports again.

Is there some configuration I'm missing for ReportViewer and/or the Angular website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was a rewrite rule in IIS forcing everything to go to https.  However the ReportViewer was not configured to work under https, only http.  The answer was to also configure ReportViewer to use https.

We didn't get to the bottom of why it only failed after the redirect to Angular.